# Mpdf automatically shrinking table if rowspan has to many data

Tags: php, laravel-8, mpdf

I'm using Mpdf and i got some strange issue regarding table rowspan. If table have more data in rowspan then they are reducing font size but instead of that i have to shift table to new page.

I have tried many solution of shrink_tables_to_fit to 1 and `<table autosize="1">` but none of them are working.

Can someone please help me how to do so?

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['shrink_tables_to_fit' => 1,
                 'tableMinSizePriority'  => true, 
                 'use_kwt'               => true]);
```

This is mpdf setup of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think that problem is when you have Table inside Table.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32813806)